# Calculation of a hard integral $\int^{1/2}_0\frac{1}{x^2-x+1} \ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}\,dx $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Calculate
$$\int^{1/2}_0\frac{1}{x^2-x+1} \cdot \ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}\,dx $$
I tried to subsitute $x=1/2-t$ so $dx=-dt$ but I just complicated more my problem.

Comment: Why do you think it can be expressed simply?  Most integrals cannot.  Maple evaluates this in terms of the dilogarithm.  It looks like Mathematica agrees.

Answer (score 12):

Substitute $t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}$

\begin{align}
&\int^{1/2}_0\frac{1}{x^2-x+1} \ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}\,dx \\
=&-2\int_{\frac13}^1 \frac{\ln t}{1+3t^2}dt
\overset{\sqrt3t\to t}= -\frac2{\sqrt3} \int_{\frac1{\sqrt3}}^{\sqrt3} \frac{\ln t-\ln\sqrt3}{1+t^2}dt\\
=& \frac{\ln 3}{\sqrt3} \int_{\frac1{\sqrt3}}^{\sqrt3} \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt = \frac{\pi\ln3}{6\sqrt3}
\end{align}
Note $\int_{\frac1{\sqrt3}}^{\sqrt3} \frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}dt \overset{t\to\frac1t} =0$

Comment: This agrees numerically with the dilogarithm answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is readily doable if you are not afraid to use complex numbers and special functions. I will focus on the indefinite integral first. First note that $$x^2-x+1=(x-e^{i\pi/3})(x-e^{-i\pi/3})$$ (two purely complex roots of $-1$) and hence $$\dfrac{1}{x^2-x+1}=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}i}{3(x-e^{-i\pi/3})}-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}i}{3(x-e^{i\pi/3})}.$$ Since $$\ln\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)$$ We can easily split the given integral into four simple integrals of the form $$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\ln (1\pm x)}{x-e^{\pm i\pi/3}}\,dx$$ and you can easily use [dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function) to solve each of them respectively.

**Added:** In general, $$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{\ln(x-a)}{(x-b)}\, dx=\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\dfrac{a-x}{a-b}\right)+\ln(x-a)\ln\left(\dfrac{x-b}{a-b}\right)+C.$$

Answer (score 1):

We use the substitution $\displaystyle x \mapsto 2 + \frac{3}{x-2}$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
I &:= \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{x^{2}-x+1}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)dx \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\operatorname{artanh}x}{x^{2}-x+1}dx \\
&= 2\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^{0}\frac{\operatorname{artanh}\left(2+\frac{3}{x-2}\right)}{\left(2+\frac{3}{x-2}\right)^{2}-\left(2+\frac{3}{x-2}\right)+1}\frac{d}{dx}\left(2+\frac{3}{x-2}\right)dx \\
&= 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\operatorname{artanh}\left(2+\frac{3}{x-2}\right)\frac{1}{x^{2}-x+1}dx \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\operatorname{artanh}x+\operatorname{artanh}\left(2+\frac{3}{x-2}\right)\right)\frac{1}{x^{2}-x+1}dx \tag{1}\\
&= \frac{\ln3}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{x^{2}-x+1}dx \\
&= \frac{\ln3}{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}+\frac{3}{4}}dx \\
&= \frac{\ln3}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{0}\frac{1}{x^{2}+1}dx \\
&= \frac{\pi\ln3}{6\sqrt{3}}
\end{align}
$$

where $(1)$ comes from adding $\displaystyle 2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\operatorname{artanh}x}{x^{2}-x+1}dx$ on both sides then dividing by $2$.

Comment: We can write closed form of this integral in very fancy way. I mean like this $$=\frac{2 \pi \ln(3)}{3 \sqrt{3}} - \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \left( \mathrm{Ti}_2(\sqrt{3}) -  \mathrm{Ti}_2\left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \right) \right)$$ I'll answer it as soon as I get time. I have somewhat different solution.

Comment: oh Accelerator! I just realized that $$\mathrm{Ti}_2(x) = \int_0^x \frac{arctan(t)}{t} dt$$ for only $x \leq 1$ so....

Comment: I did not know about that. Honestly, I think the closed form I got looks nicer than the Ti expressions, but that's my opinion. @LuckyChouhan

Comment: yeah! I think there should be $\textbf{arctanh(x)}$ rather than $\textbf{artanh(x)}$

Comment: If you want to think of it that way, then you can. It doesn't really matter to me how it's expressed as long as I'm consistent with the notation. @LuckyChouhan

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* gives:

$$\frac{\pi  \log \left(\frac{9}{8}\right)-3 i \left(\text{Li}_2\left(-\frac{1}{2}
   (-1)^{2/3}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1-\sqrt[3]{-1}}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1+\sqrt[3]{-1}}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{1-(-1)^{2/3}}\right)-\text{Li}
   _2\left(\frac{1}{1+(-1)^{2/3}}\right)+\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{3}{4}-\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{i
   \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{3}{4}+\frac{i \sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\right)}{3
   \sqrt{3}}$$

which suggests you have a lot of work ahead of you if you want to do this by hand.

Comment: Though the final answer looks terribly complicated, the solution itself is quit simple.

Comment: @Bumblebee:  Yes, a bit surprising!